# Typescript / Angular | Removing First Object of an Array

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

**my Button in .html**

```
  <button (click)="deleteFirst()">Delete First</button>
```

**My array and function in .ts:**

```
persons = [ 
    {surname: "Tom", lastname: "Brown"},
    {surname: "Ben", lastname: "Smith"},
    {surname: "Alan", lastname: "Black"},
    {surname: "Nick", lastname: "White"}]

// this does not work
deleteFirst = () => {
    this.persons[0].shift;
  }
```

How can I remove the first / last Object of an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[shift method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) does not work that way. You need to call it, preferably on an Array.

Your version should be like this, if you are ok with mutating source Array:

```
deleteFirst = () => {
  this.persons.shift();
}
```